# Mongoose response showing cached collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm running an Express app with Mongoose communicating with a Mongo DB. I have a simple page CMS to update values. On my staging environment when I update the page I can see the update reflected in my Mongo console, so I know the change is persisting to the DB. However, when I make a call to my API I see a cached response. If I restart Node I'll see the correct updated value.

Oddly enough I have other Mongoose models which seem to update fine. This also does not happen in my local development environment. Next steps to debug this would be very helpful as I can't track down where the issue would lie. I can only assume my staging environment Mongo DB has some sort of caching for this single collection and not the rest, is this a possibility?

Here's my model schema:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const HomePage = new Schema({
  marquee: {
    image: String,
    label: String,
    headline: String,
    copy: String,
    linkUrl: String,
    linkText: String,
    videoText: String,
    videoUrl: String
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date
  }
}, {
  collection: 'homepage'
});

export default mongoose.model('HomePage', HomePage);
```

Additionally, in my API's response header, I have the cache set to: `Cache-Control:max-age=0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I narrowed this down to the browser caching the response, which is odd as I've built other applications on this same platform without the issue. To resolve the issue I simply added a `?` to my URL path. So my final get request is now as follows: `http://myapp.com/api/homepage?`